# not a constant in Enum

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I am using enumeration with switch case but I am getting the following error:

> NEWS FEED is not a constant in FragmentName

This is my enum string constant,

```
 public enum FragmentName{
        FRAGMENT_NEWSFEED("NEWS FEED"),
        FRAGMENT_MESSAGES("MESSAGES"),
        FRAGMENT_EVENTS("EVENTS"),
        FRAGMENT_WHOISAROUDNME("WHOS AROUND");

        private final String text;
        private FragmentName(final String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return text;
        }
    }

//This is my function from where i check for corresponding enum constant

 public void changeTitle(String title) {
        switch (Enums_String.FragmentName.valueOf(title)) {
            case FRAGMENT_NEWSFEED:
                System.out.println("1");
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_EVENTS:
                System.out.println("2");
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_MESSAGES:
                System.out.println("3");
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_WHOISAROUDNME:
                System.out.println("4");
                break;
        }
    }
```

When I call

```
     changeTitle("NEWS FEED");
```

it creates an exception in the changeTitle function even the value passed is same, so any help would be appreciated as I have tried my every effort to solve this.

Comment: The `valueOf` call is expecting you to pass in a value like `FRAGMENT_NEWSFEED`, not the string value `NEWS FEED`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call `Enums_String.FragmentName.valueOf(title)` with `title` being `"NEWS FEED"` and why you think it should work this way (which part of documentation suggest you that this should work as you think it does)?

Comment: thanks sstan, but i want 'NEWS FEED' to send to changeTitle(String) method and corresponding, it must work

Comment: "NEWS FEED" is not the value of the enum, that's the value of the text field in the enum.  You need to pass in a string which is the name of an enum value, e.g. "FRAGMENT_NEWSFEED"

Comment: @Vikram: If you want to use your own string, then you can't use `valueOf`.  Add you own method to the enum that converts your user-defined string to an enum constant, and call that.

Comment: Basically i want to use enum with swith case with string literat, so how can i achive that??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this code to your enum

```
private static final Map<String, FragmentName> map = new HashMap<>();
static {
    for (FragmentName en : values()) {
        map.put(en.text, en);
    }
}

public static FragmentName valueFor(String name) {
    return map.get(name);
}
```

Now instead of `valueOf` use `valueFor`

```
switch (Enums_String.FragmentName.valueFor(title))
//                                ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 6):

The [valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String))

> Returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the
>   specified name. The name must match exactly an identifier used to
>   declare an enum constant in this type. (Extraneous whitespace
>   characters are not permitted.

What you want do id get the enum by a member value for that you have write a function to do so like `fromString` below

```
 public enum FragmentName {

    FRAGMENT_NEWSFEED("NEWS FEED"),
    FRAGMENT_MESSAGES("MESSAGES"),
    FRAGMENT_EVENTS("EVENTS"),
    FRAGMENT_WHOISAROUDNME("WHOS AROUND");

    private final String text;

    private FragmentName(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

    public static FragmentName fromString(String value) {
        for (FragmentName fname : values()) {
            if (fname.text.equals(value)) {
                return fname;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and replace your switch case like

```
    switch (FragmentName.fromString(title)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a method like this :

```
public static FragmentName getFragmentNameByText(String text) {
    for (FragmentName fragment : values()) {
      if (fragment.text.equals(text)) {
         return fragment;
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and call this instead of valueOf().

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to compare the string values passed in:

```
public void changeTitle(String title) {
        if(title.equals(FRAGMENT_NEWSFEED.toString())) {
            System.out.println("1");
        } else if(title.equals(FRAGMENT_MESSAGES.toString())) {
            System.out.println("2");
        } else if(title.equals(FRAGMENT_EVENTS.toString())) {
            System.out.println("3");
        } else if(title.equals(FRAGMENT_WHOISAROUDNME.toString())) {
            System.out.println("4");
        } else {
            // throw an error
        }
    }
```

You can't operate an switch off of a function call, so you have to use an if-else block.